# SQL Sum one column based on various text in another

Tags: sql, firebird

First question here so not sure exactly how to describe my issue really.

Suppose I have a very large table called "soitem". From this table, I would like to see rows "soitem.productnum", "soitem.description", and "oitem.qtyfulfilled".

This will be filtered by "soitem.datelastfullfillment" which so far looks like this:

```
SELECT soitem.productnum, SUM(soitem.qtyfulfilled) AS Total_Sold
FROM soitem
WHERE soitem.datelastfulfillment BETWEEN '9/1/15' AND '9/30/15'
GROUP BY soitem.productnum
```

I would like to take this a step further and have it only sum the `qtyfulfilled` when a different column, "qbclassid", equals (2, 3, 9, 12, 14).

If you notice, my query also does not show `soitme.description` yet since it usually gives me an error. If anyone can get that to work too, even better!

Comment: Can you please share some sample data and the result you'd like to achieve for this given data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT soitem.productnum, soitem.description, SUM(soitem.qtyfulfilled) AS Total_Sold
FROM soitem
WHERE soitem.datelastfulfillment BETWEEN '9/1/15' AND '9/30/15'
AND soitem.qbclassid IN (2, 3, 9, 12, 14)
GROUP BY soitem.productnum, soitem.description
```